# Show with comparison test that this series converges: $\sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\frac{7n^{2}+18n+2}{n^{4}+100}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> Show with comparison test that this series converges:
>   $\sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\frac{7n^{2}+18n+2}{n^{4}+100}$

$$\frac{7n^{2}+18n+2}{n^{4}+100}>\frac{7n^{2}+7n}{n^{4}}=\frac{7}{n^{2}}+\frac{7}{n^{3}}>\frac{7}{n^{2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\frac{7}{n^{2}}=7\sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$$

We know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ converges, so the complete series will converge, too.

Did I do it right?

Comment: Nope. You need an *upper* bound, not *lower*.

Comment: But how do you know that so fast? Because the denumerators degree is bigger or why?

Comment: Know what so fast? It should be somewhat intuitive, that if the non-negative sequences satisfy $a_n > b_n$, then if $\sum b_n$ converges we don't know anything about $\sum a_n$. Consider e.g. $a_n = 1$ and $b_n = 1/2^n$. However, if we bound from the other side...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find an upper bound, because having a lower bound that converges does not give you any information at all, since the series could diverge or converge. This is one way of doing things, there are many others:

$$7n^2+18n+2<7(n+4)^2<7(2n)^2=28n^2$$

In addition $n^4+100>n^4$

So $$\frac{7n^2+18n+2}{n^4+100}<\frac {28n^2}{n^4}$$
 $$\sum_{n=17}^\infty\frac{7n^2+18n+2}{n^4+100}<\sum_{n=17}^\infty\frac {28n^2}{n^4}=\sum_{n=17}^\infty\frac {28}{n^2}$$

Hence, it does converge.

Comment: Can I do it like that too?

$$\sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\frac{7n^{2}+18n+2}{n^{4}+100}<\sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\frac{7n^{2}+126n^{2}}{n^{4}}= 7\sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}+18n^{2}}{n^{4}}=7\sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\frac{\19n^{2}}{n^{4}}=
133\cdot\sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$$

Comment: @cnmesr Yeah sure, as long as the inequality holds, all terms of the series are positive, it's an upper bound, etc...

Comment: I make one more question need to be sure if I understood.